# sprite position.x

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have some sprite 'man' it's moving from side to side. How can I get position.x of this sprite from other function ? Thanks

Comment: Your question is not very clear, and you need to give more details. Perhaps some sample code?

Comment: You can't get sprite position using Move method.Instead you have to move sprite manually..For Getting Position.You can use man.position.x,man.position.y

Answer (score 0):

there is a position property in CCSprite so you can just use "manSprite.position". The position gives you a CGPoint so you can also get the x and y coordinates of your sprite like,

```
manSprite.position.x
manSprite.position.y
```

If you want to get position from another function of the same class then just declare your sprite in header (.h) file of your class (interface in objective-c).
In case you want to get position from some other class then you can declare a property for your manSprite and synthesize that poperty.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the man sprite globally.And the access that variable easily through out the class. 
If U want to get position of sprite from another class then instantiate it and then use it.